# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'NAME'.'

Tags: sql-server, database, interface

My code:

```
string SqlSelectQuery = " Select * From [KTS MANAGMENT] Where STAFF NAME=" + Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlSelectQuery, CON);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'NAME'

Comment: im new in stackoverflow also im only beginner in the field so you can just advice me easily not complain and shout

Comment: If you haven't realized it, the problem is space in your column name, you should use `[STAFF NAME]`, but of course you're also missing `'` in the code, but you should really use marc's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **always** use **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection - still the #1 vulnerability in computing.

Thus, your code should be something like this:

```
string connectionString = "......"; // typically read from config file
string query = "SELECT * FROM [KTS MANAGMENT] WHERE STAFF NAME = @Name";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = textBox1.Text;
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // read the values from the SQL data reader....
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

This approach also avoid the error you have with missing and/or mismatched single or double quotes around strings in a SQL statement ...

Comment: thanks both of u x_x too much ..... u know that i'm making this small project(of database and interface)since 3 weeks and finally i feel like **i'm all way up**